# matplotlib: group legend labels by category / multiple legend titles

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to group several legend entries into groups in pyplot? The following image visualizes what I try to achieve.

[image: 2 legend rows. Each row starts with group label and is followed by legend entries of each line that correspond to the particular group.]

Of course, I could add the group name to each line label, but unfortunately, my group labels contain several words. I want to omit these duplicates to keep the legend clean.

**Update:**

After some tries, I got the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([],[], linestyle="None", color="None", label="Group 1:") # linestyle=None --> nothing is shown, color="None" --> no impact on color cycle
plt.plot([],[], linestyle="None", color="None", label="Group 2:")
plt.plot([1,2],[4,5],linestyle="--",label="Line 1")
plt.plot([1,2],[4,6],label="Line 3")
plt.plot([1,2],[4,7],label="Line 2")
plt.plot([1,2],[4,8],label="Line 4")
leg = plt.legend(ncol=3)

for lH in leg.legendHandles:
  if lH.get_linestyle=="None":
     lH.set_visible=False # --> hide line marker from legend

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: Result of code.]

But now, there is some whitespace in front of the group labels. Adding `handlelength=0` to `plt.legend()` doesn't work. It removes the empty space, but also the lines.